# Add fixed amount of rows after value but add a different amount when there are duplicate values (one less per duplicate)

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, row

I have a list with ascending numbers that contain several duplicates. I want to add a certain amount of empty rows after each unique value such that it creates 5 rows including the value(s).

If there is a unique value (such as the number 1 for example):

```
1
empty row
empty row
empty row
empty row
```

This leads to the row that has the value (1) and 4 empty rows which make 5 in total.

If there are duplicates I need it to do the following (let's take another random number as an example):

```
22
22
empty row
empty row
empty row
```

This also leads to 5 rows in total for that unique value.

I have come up with the following.

```vb
Sub Add_Rows()
    
    Dim MyColumn As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim RowsToInsert As Long
    Dim RowsToInsert2 As Long
    Dim RowsToInsert3 As Long
    Dim RowsToInsert4 As Long
    
    MyColumn = "A"
    RowsToInsert = 4
    RowsToInsert2 = 8
    RowsToInsert3 = 12
    RowsToInsert4 = 16
    
    For x = Cells(Rows.Count, MyColumn).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        If Cells(x, MyColumn) = Cells(x - 1, MyColumn) + 1 Then
            Rows(x).Resize(RowsToInsert).Insert
        ElseIf Cells(x, MyColumn) = Cells(x - 1, MyColumn) + 2 Then
            Rows(x).Resize(RowsToInsert2).Insert
        ElseIf Cells(x, MyColumn) = Cells(x - 1, MyColumn) + 3 Then
            Rows(x).Resize(RowsToInsert3).Insert
        ElseIf Cells(x, MyColumn) = Cells(x - 1, MyColumn) + 4 Then
            Rows(x).Resize(RowsToInsert4).Insert
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

The dataset won't have more than 5 duplicates per set. Leave the 5 values be. Do not add an extra row.

Comment: what if the value repeated like more than 5 times ? need to skip to another unique number... or what to do in that case, if at all it comes

Comment: @SachinKohli The dataset won't have more than 5 duplicates per set; so at most it needs to just leave those 5 values be and not add an extra row

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code which seems to be working for sample values... Try at your end once... Logic is simple... first create a dictionary with unique values & their frequency then add rows where it's required...

Modify the code accordlingly for your use case...

```
Sub insert5rows()

Dim dict As Object
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Creating Dictionary
For Each cl In Range("A1:A" & lrow)
    dict(cl.Value) = dict(cl.Value) + 1
Next

If dict.Items()(0) > 1 And dict.Items()(0) < 5 Then
    num_check = 1
End If

' Looping through key & values of dict; where dict is the frequency
For Each Key In dict.Keys
    Set ProductID = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Key, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    ProductID.Select
    If num_check = 1 Then
        Selection.Offset(dict(Key) - 1).Select
        row_num = ActiveCell.Row
        For j = 1 To 5 - dict(Key)
            Rows(row_num).Insert
        Next
        num_check = 0
    Else
        Selection.Offset(dict(Key)).Select
        row_num = ActiveCell.Row
        For j = 1 To 5 - dict(Key)
            Rows(row_num).Insert
        Next
    End If
Next
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thanks man, 

I was occupied this evening so I haven't had the time to take a look at it. I will go and try it asap tomorrow! Your help is so very much appreciated. 

VHes

Comment: Question: Why do you use: rng As range

I don't see you using it anywhere. I am not trying to criticize you, this code is amazing, I'm merely trying to learn (I'm very curious)!

VHes

Comment: Could you potentially explain what the following statement is creating?

If dict.Items()(0) > 1 And dict.Items()(0) < 5 Then
    num_check = 1
End If

I'm assuming it adds like a 'helper' cell to every unique value but I can't quite grasp it. Does it check whether the unique value has a frequency between 1 and 5?

Comment: Sure @VHes... Answering your 1st question, I was using rng as range someplace, but later didn't use it, but forgot to remove, & you are right, there is no use of it as of now... & 2nd question regarding that condition, actually code doesn't work properly if first unique value in A column has frequency of in between 1 & 5, so just for this case I'm offsetting the selection by frequency-1... Rest of the unique values will go through the else condition... even first unique value also goes through the else condition given it's frequency is either 1 or 5...  Hoping it's clear now... Thanks :)